# How to create a subdomain with Namecheap and AWS Cloudfront?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, namecheap

I am trying to create a subdomain. I bought my domain name from namecheap and am using Cloudfront for hosting. I am trying to create a subdomain using this guide here
https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/319/78/how-can-i-setup-an-a-address-record-for-my-domain
But am lost at the part where it says I need an IP address for my A record. Namecheap support says that I get this IP address from AWS but I have no idea where I can find this. Could I get some help please?

Comment: You need to be creating a CNAME record instead of an A record.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. So it would be Type: CNAME Host: (subdomain name) Value: (Main domain) Is this correct?

Answer (score 3):

You would need:

- A `CNAME` record in Namecheap for your domain (eg `images.example.com`) that points to the CloudFront distribution name (eg `d3in9v4naaabbb.cloudfront.net`)
- An **Alternate Domain Names (CNAMEs)** entry in your CloudFront Distribution (you can do this via the CloudFront console)

See: [Using Alternate Domain Names (CNAMEs)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html)

Please note that this will not work for HTTPS by default. You will need to configure either SNI or pay for a custom domain. See: [Amazon CloudFront Custom SSL](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/custom-ssl-domains/)

Answer (score 0):

As of 2024 what worked for me is setting up CNAME record like this:
|Type  | Host | Value | TTL |
|:--|:--|:--|:--|
|CNAME Record  | @ | xxxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net | Automatic |

On the actual page, it looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3KtA.png) - NameCheap appends a dot for the value.

The effect will apply after some time (for me it was about 5 minutes). You may use https://www.nslookup.io/ to verify updated changes